# Duplicate javascript on alpha on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower

I don't know much about rails and its asset pipeline. We are having a weird issue, first of all the following is as much as I can tell about the setup, because I don't know (as I said) what other information could be relevant.

Rails 3.2.14
We are using haml
vanilla js instead of coffee
sass instead of scss
bower for some js/css frameworks instead of gem...

everything works great on localhost, but for some reason we are having some duplicate js once we deploy. But the issue is very weird, because on alpha we got the application.js with many concatenation. So far so good the problem is that some of the js that are concatenated on application.js is also being called by the browser.

let say we have application.js

```
...
// require somemodule
...
```

so on alpha we got somemodule concatenated in application.js but we also recive somemodule.js in the browser... we are not invoking somemodule out of application.js so we don't understand why is this happening.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Update: I include bower as I tag because backend told me that for the bower's assets are not being compiled

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are requiring *only* your manifest file, and that your manifests aren't be expanded into their component files. Check that `config.assets.debug` is set to `false` in production and `true` in development. In development, you will have many JavaScript `<script>` tags, one for each file in `app/assets/javascripts`. In production, you will have a single `<script src="/assets/application-XXXXX.js">` script tag.

The issue you may be facing is that, if you have both precompiled your assets, *and* have `config.assets.debug` set to `true`, you will have one completely copy of your scripts included via a `<script src="/assets/application-XXXXX.js">` and then a duplicate copy of each of the component scripts included.

Comment: Hi @meagar... thanks for your response... let me try tomorrow with me coworkers and I'll let you know :)